# UISearchBar Cancel Button function not working

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I want to do sth. each time the cancel button is tapped inside the searchBar.
It is not working and not even calling the searchBarCancelButtonClicked method.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iho1V.png

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchbar.delegate = self    
   } 

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("Cancel Button Clicked")
   }
}
```

Comment: How did  add `UISearchBar ` in `UITableViewController ` Make sure of this `UIViewController`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It is a search bar outlet connected from a storyboard.

Comment: ok, please add screenshot from this controller in storyboard

Comment: Ok i have added a image to my question.

Comment: this is UIViewController not UITableViewController

Comment: It is a UITableViewController. Don't know what you mean.